# MongoDB query for nested array of specific object

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I am a new mongodb user, this why I am asking this question. I have a document, in this document I have 3 objects under one _id.

When I am filtering  `{ "people.age":  { $in: [24] } }`  I am getting full this document. But I want to see only the matching object. Like for age 24, I just want to see object 2, not object 0 and 1.

Is it possible to show only the matching object? If you kindly explain me it will be helpful for me.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `$` for projection.

> Query 1

```
db.collection.find({
  "people.age": {
    $in: [
      24
    ]
  }
},
{
  "people.$": 1
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Query 1)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HUyVhertMmj)

If you just to search people by certain age, you may use the below query as well:

> Query 2

```
db.collection.find({
  "people.age": 24
},
{
  "people.$": 1
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Query 2)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kRGiV9dNoWK)

Note: `$` will returns only the first element of the array.

---

You may look for aggregation query as:

1. `$match` - Filter the document by `age`.
2. `$project` - Decorate output documents. With `$filter` operator to filter the document in `people` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "people.age": 24
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "people": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$people",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.age",
              24
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Aggregation pipeline)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Wry08gP5BwW)

---

**Reference**

[Project Specific Array Elements in the Returned Array](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

Comment: Thank you Yong Shun, for you suggestion. But If I have 2 same age in 2 different objects, still I am getting only one result.

Comment: Hi done update the answer. Think aggregation query is more suitable for your case.

Comment: Hi, Yong Shun, thank you for your idea. It is really helping me to understand mondobd aggregation.